# Convert character vector to a new vector of substrings

Tags: r, regex, string

Let's say I have a character vector `a <- c("take", "me", "home", "run", "do", "eat")`.  I'd like to create a function that can take in this character vector and some value n, and then say `n=2` you get:

`c("take me", "home run", "do eat")`

and if `n=3` then you get:

`c("take me home", "run do eat")`

What is the most efficient way (fastest and most scalable) to achieve this?

Comment: I suppose I meant the fastest and most scalable code.

Comment: Thanks...I edited and added as part of your question.  I deleted that comment and will delete this one in a bit to keep this post clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a <- c("take", "me", "home", "run", "do", "eat")
l <- length(a)

n <- 2    
tapply(a, rep(1:ceiling(l/n), rep(n, ceiling(l/n)))[1:l], paste, collapse = " ")
         1          2          3 
 "take me" "home run"   "do eat" 

n <- 3
tapply(a, rep(1:ceiling(l/n), rep(n, ceiling(l/n)))[1:l], paste, collapse = " ")
             1              2 
"take me home"   "run do eat" 

n <- 4
tapply(a, rep(1:ceiling(l/n), rep(n, ceiling(l/n)))[1:l], paste, collapse = " ")
                 1                  2 
"take me home run"           "do eat"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this out.

```
library(dplyr)
a <- c("take", "me", "home", "run", "do", "eat")

group_string <- function(vec, n){
    df <- data_frame(string = vec, ind = ceiling(grep("^.*?", a)/ n)) %>% 
        group_by(ind) %>% 
        summarise(string = paste(string, collapse = " "))
    return(df$string)
}

group_string(a,2)
[1] "take me"  "home run" "do eat"  

group_string(a,3)
[1] "take me home" "run do eat"
```

Answer (score 0):

This function does the trick.

```
conFun <- function(v,n){
  while(length(v)>0){
    print(v[1:n])
    v <- v[-(1:n)]
  }
}

conFun(a,3)

[1] "take" "me"   "home"
[1] "run" "do"  "eat"
```